# Android DialogFragment How to remove 1px border

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have a DialogFragment that shows a small  black border (it seems 1 px width) around the dialog. I want my dialog to be flat, with not borders neither gradients. How can I remove that?

I've tried with the following code without success:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  ...

  AlertDialog result = builder.create();
  result.setView(rootView, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  result.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
  return result;
  //return builder.create();
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
public class QuickActionFragment extends DialogFragment {

  @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       Dialog m_dialog = new Dialog(QuickActionFragment.this, R.style.Dialog_No_Border);
      LayoutInflater m_inflater = LayoutInflater.from(CustomDialogActivity.this);
      View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.view_quick_action, null, false);
        // SET ALL THE VIEWS
        m_dialog.setTitle(null);
    m_dialog.setContentView(m_view);
    m_dialog.show();
        return dialog;
 }
}
```

Add the Dialog_No_Border style in your res/value/style.xml file.

```
<style name="Dialog_No_Border">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_color</item>
</style>
```

Clean project then Run

Comment: Thx! It is working fine. I had to use @android:color/transparent instead of @color/transparent_color